# Getting specific Rails version of a Rails 2.x app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can figure out a Rails app being built on Rails 2.x , as it has a  script/server file.

But How do I find which specific Rails version, the app is written in.
doc/README_FOR_APP for this app, does not seem to contain anything helpful in this regard. Any other way I can figure the specific Rails Version for the app.

Comment: my rails version is 3.2.3 . So i am trying to tinker with a 2.X Rails app with rails 3 installed. Is this viable?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `script/about` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in your config/environment.rb. Just run

```
 ./script/runner 'puts RAILS_GEM_VERSION'
```